# postgresql SET search_path TO SCHEMA_NAME is safe?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL has an option to query a particular schema.

> SET search_path TO SCHEMA_NAME

Can it cause any artifacts ?

How safe is to use it ?

Comment: What do you understand under artefacts? The command is setting a search path where Postgres is looking for database objects.

Comment: What does `safe` exactly mean? `search_path` does not provide any additional permissions

Answer (score 4):

Changing the `search_path` changes which tables are seen without a schema qualification.

If you have a `SECURITY DEFINER` function, a user might be able to trick it into affecting a different table by changing the `search_path` before running it. This is only possible if you ignored the PostgreSQL documentation's advice to always use `SET search_path` in the function's options.

Similarly, a webapp might be tricked into affecting a different table if a user could inject a `set search_path`. But if they can inject that, they can inject malicious SQL directly.

The main issue is with `SECURITY DEFINER` functions, and is easily solved by following the manual's advice.

Comment: can is cause issue when we have a connection pool and accessing different schema over the same connection ?

Comment: Your connection pool should be configured to run a `DISCARD ALL` command when returning a connection to the pool. See [`DISCARD ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html). That'll ensure the connection is reset to default state. Each user of the connection should issue a `SET search_path` before running queries.